# Matplotlib plot with ConnectionPaths objects layout issues

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a script that plots point correspondences between images:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np   
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch, Rectangle
     
dpi = 100
fontsize = 8
offset = 0
img_size = (235, 190)

image_1 = np.zeros(img_size)
image_2 = np.zeros(img_size)
num_points = 50
points_x_1 = np.random.randint(190, size=(num_points,))
points_y_1 = np.random.randint(235, size=(num_points,))
points_x_2 = np.random.randint(190, size=(num_points,))
points_y_2 = np.random.randint(235, size=(num_points,))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(2 * img_size[1] / dpi, (img_size[0] + offset) / dpi), dpi=dpi)  
axes[0].imshow(image_1)
axes[1].imshow(image_2)
colors = np.random.randint(256, size=(num_points, 3)) / 255.0
axes[0].scatter(points_x_1, points_y_1, s=20, c=colors)
axes[1].scatter(points_x_2, points_y_2, s=20, c=colors)
for i in range(num_points):
    point_1 = (points_x_1[i], points_y_1[i])
    point_2 = (points_x_2[i], points_y_2[i])
    con = ConnectionPatch(xyB=point_1, xyA=point_2, coordsB="data", coordsA="data", 
                          axesB=axes[0], axesA=axes[1], color=colors[i], linewidth=1)
    axes[1].add_artist(con)
```

This results with an overlap of the axes ticks of one image with the other.

[image]

When I try to add `fig.tight_layout()` at the end of the script the image's size is drastically diminished:

[image]

Is it possible to keep the images large and avoid the ticks overlapping?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `fig.tight_layout()` you could try `fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.3)`

Comment: It worked! Would you mind posting a solution and describing the difference between `tight_layout()` and your solution? I couldn't find it anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @JohanC, removing `fig.tight_layout()` and replacing it with `fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.3)` did the trick.